# Beamer slides to EDITABLE PPT?

Tags: beamer, pdf, powerpoint

I created slides in Beamer awhile back. I need to convert the slides to editable PPT format. I'd prefer not to have to do that by creating the PPT from scratch.

I tried searching for this question, but everything I was able to find is a bit dated, with users commenting that the solutions (pdf to PPT converters) didn't work well. I wanted to see if there's any better solutions nowadays.

Are there any reliable converter tools?

I'm on a Macbook, but might be able to get access to a PC if needed.

Comment: Not that I know of. PDF is pretty much an end-format. PDFs are usually not for anything else than being printed or looked at.

Comment: You can insert PDF figures in PPT on mac.